# Android Launcher Won't Launch (Check My XML)

Tags: android, xml, manifest, launcher

```
[2012-01-23 15:55:42 - MyApp] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-01-23 15:55:42 - MyApp] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

I get this error on the Console whenever I try to start my app. I've read all the other questions posted on here regarding this, and all the people just needed to fix their AndroidManifest.xml file.

Below is my entire Android Manifest, which I've looked over about 50 times for errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="danny.personal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Home" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="danny.personal.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".ContactHome" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="danny.personal.CONTACTHOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<action android:name="danny.personal.HOME" />
```

To:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Assuming that's your **main** activity. Also, modify the XML block associated with your second activity (`ContactHome`) to the following:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:name=".ContactHome" />
```

This of course assumes that `Home` is your main activity and `ContactHome` is launched from within `Home`.

Comment: Thanks! I had to change the first part, the `<action android:name` however the second part just have me an error since that `/>` is closing the `<activity>` tag.

Comment: @DannyF247 For the second part, replace the _whole_ `activity` block (corresponding to `ContactHome`) with what I posted above.

Comment: @DannyF247 I don't _think_ you need an intent filter for your second activity. Anyway try it both ways, try it the way I suggested and see if it works. If not, go back to the way you had it before :)